# In Spring 16 Napili getting "Invalid Page" error

Tags: case, napili

We must moved to the the Spring 16 version of Napili from the Winter 16 version. When we click on the cases Tab, we are getting an "invalid page" notification.

I don't think anything changed in our profiles or sharing settings.

[image]

Comment: Please share the URL once you click on My Cases ? Also inspect element in your console to see if there are issues .

Comment: https://sgcommunity.force.com/s/recordlist/Case/00Ba000000AHcnzEAD

I am not seeing any errors when inspecting the element, but I am not a developer and rarely use that so I may be missing something.

Comment: what component are you getting the error on?  It looks like maybe there's more of the page that does load successfully?

Comment: I believe the component is the case list view.

Comment: @ThaddeusWard, I am seeing the same error when trying to view the case details. Did you solve this issue?

Comment: In my case, the error was because of the not configuring the sharing settings for the community. Once I added the sharing settings under community settings the 'Invalid Page' is gone. Hope it helps somebody in the future.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was in the navigation component.  I had selected a default picklist value for the cases navigation element that was not available to the community users.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this issue by selecting the "Default" list view from the navigation menu. If you select "All Cases" view, you will get that "Invalid Page" error.